# Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0. [Github Actions]

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

My laravel workflow:

```
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ productionServer ]

jobs:
  create-deployment-artifacts:

    name: Create deployment artifacts
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    outputs:
      deployment-matrix: ${{ steps.export-deployment-matrix.outputs.deployment-matrix }}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Create deployment artifact
      env:
        GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}

      run: tar -czf ${GITHUB_SHA}.tar.gz *

    - name: Store artifact for distribution
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: app-build
        path: ${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz
    
    - name: Export deployment matrix
      id: export-deployment-matrix
      run: |
        CFG=$(echo $(cat server_config.json) | sed 's/ //g')
        echo "::set-output name=deployment-matrix::$CFG"

  prepare-release-on-server:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: Prepare release"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: create-deployment-artifacts
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
```

Server_config.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "Demo",
        "ip": "13.18.34.211",
        "username": "ubuntu",
        "password": "asdhnasdjia9si8d989sdkjsjd_sdu89ds",
        "dbName": "demoDB",
        "dbPassword": "demo",
        "appUrl": "https://Demo.com/",
        "port": "22",
        "beforeHooks": "echo done",
        "afterHooks": "echo done",
        "path": "/var/www/html/Demo"
    }
]
```

Output in github workflow:

[image]

I want this workflow to fetch my server config from server_config and update in the matrix so that I can deploy my source code to multiple server in a single run.

Comment: The complaint points to line 17 of the YML file, which contains the string: `server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}`. The complaint further says that there is invalid JSON. I'm not sure what laravel does with this line, but that's where to look. (This has nothing to do with Git.)